# Show that $f *g \in C(\mathbb{T})$ for $f \in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ and $g \in L^q(\mathbb{T})$ by minkowski integral inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

.  Let $1 \leq p,q\leq \infty$ be conjugate exponents and let $\mathbb{T}$ be the torus. I want to show that there is a continuous extension of $|f*g|$ to $C(\mathbb{T})$.

I know that the claim in the title is true because if $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$, for $f_n$ continuous, then we have that $osc_\delta (f_n*g) \leq osc_{\delta, L^p}(f_n) |g|_{L^q}\leq osc_{\delta, L^\infty} (f_n) |g|_{L^q} \to 0 $ as $\delta \to 0$ so that $f_n*g$ is uniformly continuous and $|f*g-f_n*g|_\infty \leq |(f-f_n)|_p |g|_q \to 0$ which shows that $f*g$ is uniformly continuous.

A postiori it seems that a density argument should not be necessary and one should be able to argue directly using minkowski integral inequality or looking at $osc_{\delta, L^p}(f) |g|_{L^q}\leq osc_{\delta, L^\infty} (f_n) |g|_{L^q}$.  How can I show that the convolution is continuous directly in this way?

---

edit:  sorry everyone:  f is not uniformly continuous.  $f*g$ is obviously.

Comment: Writing is not clear!

Comment: you have to use $\|f\|_p = \sup_{\|g\|_q = 1} \int |fg| d\mu, \qquad \tfrac{1}{p} + \tfrac{1}{q} = 1$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality ?

Comment: sorry, I made the question late at night and it didn't make sense.  do you still think that your comment can be used?

Comment: The problem comes down to showing that translation is a continuous operation on $L^p$ for $1 \le p < \infty$. Even if you chop the function off to be bounded and try to apply the bounded convergence theorem to the translates, that doesn't seem to be enough. It's remarkable that an approximation argument works so easily when nothing else seems to work at all.

Comment: oh okay.  Now I know what I was confused about.  So the $L_p$ oscillation of any $L_p$ function tends to 0 as $\delta \to 0$.  I was confused about this because I had a homework assignment where I showed that the rate of decay of the $L^2$ oscillation in terms of delta was the same as 1/the rate of decay of the tail of $\sum_{n>N} |\hat f(n)|^2$  in term of $N$, when the rate of decay was $\delta^\alpha$, $0 <\alpha <1$.  Thus I didn't realize that this just quantified how fast the oscillation tended to 0, and was not a condition on the oscillation going to 0 - it happens automatically..

Comment: Now that you mention it, the result that translation is a continuous operation rings a bell.  I remember having to prove this when showing that $|\phi_n*f-f|_p \to 0$ for $f$ in $L^p$ and $\phi_n$ an approximate identity.

Comment: This was how I did it a year back.  But in my class, usingmuscalu and schlag, my teacher did it via a density argument, the same way I resorted to it in my question.